# Spring mvc select from enum - selected value issue

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to use spring mvc form select with ENum values. I can'y put the selected value.

This is the Enum:

```
public enum MessagesType {

SL(4, 0, 9000000, 9999999), 
BL(1,2, 1000000, 1999999);

private Integer moduleCode;

private Integer subModuleCode;

private Integer rangeMin;

private Integer rangeMax;

    MessagesType(Integer moduleCode, Integer subModuleCode, Integer rangeMin, Integer rangeMax) {
        this.moduleCode = moduleCode;
        this.subModuleCode = subModuleCode;
        this.rangeMax = rangeMax;
        this.rangeMin = rangeMin;
    }

... (getters ans setters)
```

This is the form call:

```
<td><form:label path="type">message type:</form:label></td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="type"  items="${messagesTypes}" itemValue="${messageEditContextDto.type}" />
                </td>
```

messageEditContextDto is a model bean which holds the type and a bunch of other fields I need:

```
public class MessageEditContextDto implements Serializable {

    private MessagesType type;

    ... 
}
```

I get this exception:
*org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'SL' of bean class [com.sapiens.alis.updater.domain.enums.MessagesType]: Bean property 'SL' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?*

Help please...

Thanks Idob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would normally get the values of the enum. For simplicity I am changing your code a bit.

```
public enum MessagesType {
    SL("4"), 
    BL("2");

    private String value;

    private MessagesType(String theValue) {
        this.value = theValue;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value 
    }
}
```

Form  call:

```
    <td><form:label>message type:</form:label></td>
    <td>
          <form:select path="type">
              <!-- Characters edition-->
              <c:forEach var="item" items="${MessagesType.values}">
                  <form:option value="{item.value}"><spring:eval expression="item"/></form:option>
              </c:forEach>
          </form:select>
    </td>
```

This will give you some idea about how you can go about achieving your goal.